# What is a life of HttpServletRequest object?

Tags: java, servlets, request

I have doubt about `HttpServletRequest` life object. Is the `request` object destroyed after it got into `controller`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The lifetime of an `HttpServletRequest` object is just that: the time of serving an HTTP Servlet request.

It may be created right before calling the servlet's `doGet()`, `doPost()` etc. methods, and may be destroyed right after that. It is only valid to use it during serving a request.

**Note:** However Servlet containers *may* reuse `HttpServletRequest` objects for multiple requests (and this is typically the case), but they will be "cleaned" or reset so no objects (like parameters or attributes) will leak between requests. This is simply due to performance issue: it is much faster and cheaper to reset an `HttpServletRequest` object than to throw away an existing one and create a new one.

In a typical Servlet container implementation if an HTTP request comes in, an `HttpServletRequest` is created right when the HTTP input data of the request is parsed by the Servlet container. The whole request might be lazily initialized (e.g. parameters might only be parsed and populated if they are really accessed e.g. via `getParameter()` method). Then this `HttpServletRequest` (which extends `ServletRequest`) is passed through the Servlet filters and then passed on to `Servlet.service()` which will dispatch the call to `doGet()`, `doPost()` etc based on the HTTP method (`GET`, `POST`, `PUT` etc.). Then the request will still be alive until the request-response pair cycles back throughout the filter chain. And then it will be destroyed or reset (before it is used for another HTTP request).

Comment: If somebody passes the HttpServletRequest Object to some other place,then the HttpServletRequest Object will remain beyond the request cycle.What do you think?

Comment: Yes, you may do that, but using a request object outside of the request cycle is invalid. So it is strongly not recommended.

Comment: @icza you have no idea how much u have just helped me right now - we had an issue for quite a while where `HttpServletRequest` was passed around via spring's `@Async` and at some point it's fields where getting cleared. Your input - "However Servlet containers may reuse HttpServletRequest objects for multiple requests (and this is typically the case), but they will be "cleaned" or reset so no objects (like parameters or attributes) will leak between requests" is **absolutely spot on!**. Thank you!