# HttpServletRequest details returning null with @Async Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, servlets

I would like to extract the URI of an incoming request.

I have the following code in my application - a `@RequestMapping` which is `@Async`. I would like to extract the path URI via `request.getRequestURI()` but it returns `null` when the `@Async` annotation is present, otherwise, when it is not, the output is as desired. Is this intended behaviour, if so, why? And how can I obtain the same output with `@Async`? Removing `@Async` is not an easy option for me as I would like to use it for performance.

```
@Async
@RequestMapping("{name}/**")
@ResponseBody
public void incomingRequest(
        @PathVariable("name") String name,
        HttpMethod method,
        HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response)
{
    String URI = request.getRequestURI(); // <-- null with @Async
}
```

It seems that in general, all request related parameters are being lost, which is not what I want; I need to extract them for my program.

Comment: I tried this locally as you have it and it works for me so I'm not sure what else you have going on to cause the null. However, I would suggest you create a service class that takes your request data and does something with it. You can mark the service method with @Async instead of your Controller and call the service from your controller.

Comment: Here https://stackoverflow.com/a/77058559/418599 my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest clue to the reason of empty `HttpServletRequest` I could find was comment to the answer on this post: [What is a life of HttpServletRequest object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26036459/what-is-a-life-of-httpservletrequest-object)

To solve your issue you can try 2 approaches here:

1. Since your method is `void` you can manually start a new thread from `incomingRequest` method using, for example, [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html).
2. Or, try with returning `CompletableFuture` from your method, like so:

```
@Async
@RequestMapping("{name}/**")
@ResponseBody
public CompletableFuture<Void> incomingRequest(
        @PathVariable("name") String name,
        HttpMethod method,
        HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response)
{
    String URI = request.getRequestURI(); // should get the right non null path
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
}
```

Comment: Would he still need the ```@Async``` if he returned a Callable<Void>? I think by doing so, Spring will know to execute asynchronously.

Comment: I don't think so. Without annotation it will still run on http request thread. You can try yourself and check the current thread.

Comment: Actually, just tried it. It does work but you have to return a Callable<Void>, or lambda will do it ```return () -> {log.debug("callable:" + request.getRequestURI()); return null;};```.   More on it here: https://spring.io/blog/2012/05/07/spring-mvc-3-2-preview-introducing-servlet-3-async-support .   But either way, there's no reason why OP should be getting null which is the mystery.

Comment: To add, I tried it all 4 ways (@Asyc, regular plain way, Callable, and @Async + CompletableFuture). In all cases, getRequestURI was not null and the right value so I'm suspecting there's something else at play here.

Comment: What you you using for the path when it happens?

Comment: A simple path that looked like `baseUrl/name`. Sometimes it would print `null` and sometimes  `baseUrl/name`.

Comment: Did the completable future answer and it works great. With @Async + return void still a problem. I really wish I wouldn't have to use futures this way and more importantly, I wish to understand what's going on.

Comment: @Zeruno.Glad it worked for you. You can accept the answer to show others that it can be a solution. With Spring you sometimes need to debug deep in their codebase since documentation can miss on details.